# Gatsby source plugin only showing last item in array in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When I console log after I run build 6 objects show up in my drinks array. They also show up when I run develop. But when I query graphQL only the last object in my array is available. I am new to gatsby and graphQL so included image just in case my query was off.
Code is from my gatsby-node.js file:

```
exports.sourceNodes = async (
    { actions, createContentDigest, createNodeId,}
  ) => {
  const NODE_TYPE = "CocktailRecipes";
    try{ 
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=vodka`)
    const data = await response.json();
    const {drinks} = data;
    console.log(drinks)
    drinks.forEach((drink) => {
      actions.createNode({
        ...drink,
        id: createNodeId(`${NODE_TYPE }-${drink.id}`),
        parent:null,
        children:[],
        internal:{
          type:NODE_TYPE,
          content:JSON.stringify(drink),
          contentDigest: createContentDigest(drink)
        }
      })
    })
    }
    catch(error){ 
      console.log("ERROR")
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

[only one object showing in graphQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He9qC.jpg)

If anyone could help it would be very much appreciated as I've been banging my head on a wall for awhile now. I've done a gatsby clean. I've tried map instead of forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced exactly the same issue as you a few months ago and, in my case was that I needed to set a valid internal `id` for each element to allow GraphQL to create a proper schema for each node if not, the `id` is overridden in each element and it only takes the last one.

In your case, it seems that some field is wrong, making the following expression invalid:

```
    id: createNodeId(`${NODE_TYPE }-${drink.id}`),
```

Try debugging more what's receiving and changing it to some hardcoded value. Something like:

```
    id: drink.id,
```

Keep in mind that, if the `id`s are different for each node, you don't need to use [`createNodeId` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-api-helpers/#createNodeId) for debugging purposes (but it's recommended).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the issue.